# How to bring back CONTROL + F (Quick Find) in Visual Studio 2015 & 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, find, visual-studio-2015, ctrl

Where did `CTRL+F` (Quick Find) go?

It's annoying that I have to use `CTRL+H` (Replace) instead of Quick Find.

How to bring it back?

Comment: What do you mean? In 2013, for me, `CTRL + F` brings up the "Find" dialog just as it has in previous versions of Visual Studio. Have you perhaps unbound the shortcut?

Comment: Ctrl+F could be re-assigned to some other command. I would use FeinCtrl tool from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2c3354bd-8efd-4ea7-9099-a5fd80ca4185 to see if there is a collision.

Comment: @TZHX: It's already unbounded whenever I install VS 2013 or 2015.
Vlad: FeinCtrl shows this:          **97,{5EFC7975-14BC-11CF-9B2B-00AA00573819},"Edit.Find","Global","Ctrl+","F","",""**

Comment: After installing FeinCtrl, the shortcut is working. Strange. Anyway, thank you.